# Promises and condition from async call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I'm implementing my service using Node.js with AWS DynamoDB (`aws-sdk`).

It's unclear for me how to implement the following scenario with promises:

1. I get a request to modify an entity with specified attributes
2. I'm trying to find the entity in the DB (async call `find`)
3. If the entity not found then create one with initial state (async call `createInitialStateObject`)
4. Modify the entity (which was in the DB before or just created on step 3) according to specific rules (async call `applyModifications`)

This is my first attempt:

```
function scenario(params) {
    find(params).then((data) => {
        let objectExists = checkExistense(data);
        if (!objectExists) {
            createInitialStateObject(params).then((data) => {
                console.log("Object created");
                // OK
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error("Object not created");
                // exit and return error
            });
        }
        applyModifications(params).then((data) => {
            // OK, return data
        }).catch((err) => {
            // exit and return error
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        // exit and return error
    });
}
```

But the flaw here is that creation could happen before the modification, it's not bound to happen one after another.

The other attempt works, but looks a bit weird. I create an empty promise to call in case the object already exists:

```
function scenario(params) {
    find(params).then((data) => {
        let conditionalPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
        let objectExists = checkExistense(data);
        if (!objectExists) {
            conditionalPromise = createInitialStateObject(params);
        }
        conditionalPromise.then((data) => {
            applyModifications(params).then((data) => {
                // OK, return data
            }).catch((err) => {
                // exit and return error
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            // exit and return error
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        // exit and return error
    });
}
```

How it should be implemented in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating 'empty' or sync. Promises isn't unusual. There is even a short way of doing that: `Promise.resolve(value)` creates and resolves a Promise immediately.

Besides that you should make use of proper chaining and stop nesting things so much. Once you are in a chain, you don't even need to resolve an empty promise as a return value of a non thenable object is interpreted as exactly this.

```
function scenario(params) {
  return find(params)
    .then(data => {
      let objectExists = checkExistense(data);
      if (!objectExists) {
        return createInitialStateObject(params);
      }
      // if we return nothing (or null in your case) this will be the same as return Promise.resolve()
      return null;
    })
    .then(data => applyModifications(params))
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
        // exit and return error
}
```

Comment: `a return value of a non thenable object` is equivalent to return `Promise.resolve(value);` - because according to the [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40) `.then` must return a Promise